# For what values of $n\in\mathbf{N}$, $n^{4}-7n^{3}-2n^{2}+n+4$ is multiple of 9.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am given a suggestion which is to use that if $a\equiv b \mod n$ then for all $m\in\mathbf{N}$ we have $a^m\equiv b^m\mod n$. But I don't know how to apply it and where to bigging this problem really. Any suggestions in how to attack this problem?

Comment: Just try the values $\{0,1,\cdots, 8\}$.

Comment: Since $3 \not\mid n$, you only need to try the values $\{1,2,4,5,7,8\}$.

Comment: or $\{\pm1,\pm2,\pm4\}$

Comment: $n=4,8,13,17,22,26,31$ are a few

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The suggestion you were given is a good one. It implies that, given any polynomial $p$, $$x\equiv y\pmod n\implies p(x)\equiv p(y)\pmod n.$$
In this case, we can take $p(x)=x^4-7x^3-2x^2+x+4$, so we need to find all $x$ for which $p(x)\equiv 0$ mod $9$. Now, every integer $x$ is congruent to an element of the set $\{0,1,2,\dots,8\}$ (these are all the possible remainders of division by $9$), so we just need to test if $p(0),p(1),\dots,p(8)$ is $0$ mod $9$ to solve the question.

You could just test all $9$ values directly, or we might consider slightly simplifying the problem by making a few observations. First, if $3\mid n$ then $9\mid n^2$, so all powers of $n$ other than $1$ and $n$ are congruent to $0$ mod $9$, so $p(n)\equiv n +4\in \{1,4,7\}$ mod $9$ and cannot be $0$. From here, just test the other possibilities: $x\equiv 1,2,4,5,7,8$.

Comment: If $p(n)=n^4-7n^3-2n^2+n+4,$ then e.g. $p(13)=12861=9 \cdot 1429.$

Comment: @coffeemath there's no need to consider such large numbers, though. We might as well consider $p(4)$.

Comment: YiFan.. Yes I see. Are you just getting *some* solutions using the small numbers, since larger ones can be found by the method mentioned?

Comment: @coffeemath we reduced the problem of finding all integer solutions to that of finding residue classes mod $9$ which work. Once we've found all the elements of $\{0,1,\dots,8\}$ that work, adding a multiple of $9$ to that will give you all possible integer solutions.